# Is there a way to turn off narrator scan mode on for specific XAML page in UWP?

Tags: accessibility, uwp-xaml, accessibility-api

When Narrator is on, It's automatically scanning the page and reading entire page content. I need stop Narrator scan mode on in UWP. Is there is any specific API's are available to use in UWP.
Please provide any solution or suggestion to handle this issue.

Comment: Any updates about your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there is any specific API's are available to use in UWP.

I have to say no, the Narrator is controlled by the system. Currently, there is no API from UWP that could directly control the behavior of Narrator.

Comment: If you really need such kind of API, you could submit a feature request in the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu.